# PHP take id of each object from loop and use another page

Tags: php

I have a code that retrieves data from database. I need to show detailed information of clicked object on another page according to the id of the object.
How can I achieve this? When I set $_SESSION and use in another page it takes only last value.
Codes retrieves info is as following.

```
<?php
include("misc.inc");
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Couldn't connect database");
$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM ad ORDER BY training_start desc";
$result =   mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
echo    "<table cols='4'  cellspacing='25'>";
echo    "<th>ID</th>";
echo    "<th>Training Name</th>";
echo    "<th>Trainer Name</th>";
echo    "<th>Training Dates</th>";
echo    "<th>Registration Starts</th>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

extract($row );


echo    "<tr><td >$id</td>";
echo    "<td  ><a href='ad_details.php'>$training_name</a></td>";
echo    "<td >$trainer_name</td>";
echo    "<td >$training_start - $training_end</td>";
echo    "<td >$reg_start</td></tr>";

}

echo    "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: You should pass the ID of the record you want to show on the details page. On the details page fetch the record using the given ID and display its details. (ad_details.php?id=YOUR_ID)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line :

```
echo    "<td  ><a href='ad_details.php'>$training_name</a></td>";
```

To :

```
echo    "<td  ><a href='ad_details.php?id=$id'>$training_name</a></td>";
```

Then on details.php use get method to get the id

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){

 $currentID = $_GET['id'];

 // Then select what you want where id = $currentID


}else{

    //id not set redirect back / return error
}
```

> Side Note : if you are not using prepared statements I strongly advice
>   that you start using them.

Comment: $currentID = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null); Or else you might get that pesky invalid index ;)

Comment: @NahidMirzayev glad it worked, you may accept the answer if it helped solve ur probelm